# How do I do a time series analysis as part of running a function in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have this:

formulas_count_stats.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from df_count_stats import df, df1

df = df
df1 = df1

class Data_load_compare_0:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(df, delimiter=';')

        '''
        Data information section from df  = basic stats

        '''

    def get_EDA_columns(self):
        return self.df.columns

    def get_EDA_info(self):
        return self.df.info()

    def get_EDA_describe(self):
        return self.df.describe()

    def get_EDA_shape(self):
        return self.df.shape

    def get_EDA_value_counts(self):
        return self.df.value_counts()

    def get_EDA_isnull(self):
        return self.df.isnull()

    def get_EDA_dtypes(self):
        return self.df.dtypes

    def get_EDA_isna(self):
        return self.df.isna()

    def get_EDA_nunique(self):
        return self.df.nunique()

    def get_EDA_sort_dipl(self):
        return self.df.query("col1 == 'X'")

    def get_EDA_sort_bach(self):
        return self.df.query("col1 == 'Y'")

    def get_EDA_sort_by_line(self):
        return self.df.groupby(['col2', 'col1', 'col3']).agg(['count'])# groupby(['User Name', 'col2'])['col1'].size().reset_index(name='counts')

    '''
    Time series
    '''
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    def get_time_series(self):
        df['Logon Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Logon Time'], errors='coerce')
        df['Year'] = df.index.dt.year
        df['month'] = df.index.dt.month
        df['day'] = df.inde.dt.day
        df['hour'] = df.index.dt.hour
        df['week'] = df.index.dt.week
        df['count'] = df['User Name']
        return df.groupby([df['Logon Time'].dt.year, df['Logon Time'].dt.month]).sum().plot.bar()
    plt.show()
```

...and running the functions from main_count_stats.py (loading data from df_count_stats.py):

```
from df_count_stats import df_load, df1_load
from formulas_count_stats import Data_load_compare_0, Data_load_compare_1

myData = Data_load_compare_0(df_load)
myData1 = Data_load_compare_1(df1_load)

EDA_stats_00_0 = myData.get_EDA_columns()
EDA_stats_01_0 = myData.get_EDA_nunique()
EDA_stats_02_0 = myData.get_EDA_shape()
EDA_stats_03_0 = myData.get_EDA_info()
EDA_stats_04_0 = myData.get_EDA_isna()
EDA_stats_05_0 = myData.get_EDA_isnull()
EDA_stats_06_0 = myData.get_EDA_describe()
EDA_stats_07_0 = myData.get_EDA_dtypes()
EDA_stats_08_0 = myData.get_EDA_sort_bach()
EDA_stats_09_0 = myData.get_EDA_sort_dipl()
EDA_stats_10_0 = myData.get_EDA_sort_by_line()
EDA_stats_11_0 = myData.get_time_series()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../.../main_count_stats.py", line 25, in <module>
    EDA_stats_11_0 = myData.get_time_series()
  File "C:\...\...\...\formulas_count_stats.py", line 59, in get_time_series
    df['Year'] = df.index.dt.year
AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

I hoped that my attempt to integrate a simple time series analysis as part of an otherwise well-functioning formulas_count_stats.py would work. Obviously, it does not. I did change the index to a 'to_datetime' format.

How can I solve this?

Comment: instead of using `df.index.dt.[...]`, it seems easiest to use `df['Logon Time'].dt.[...]`

Comment: You're right, MrFuppes. Your solution works, however, now I need the main_count_stats.py to generate the actual plot. Tried this, but got AxesSubplot error: test = myData.get_time_series()

# importing the required module
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(test)
plt.show()

Comment: honestly, I don't fully understand how you want to process your data with that class, seems a little convoluted to me ^^

Comment: You may be right, if you have a better way, I am all ears...;o) Looking forward to seeing your upgraded solution

Answer (score 0):

or you can convert the index to `Series` and use `.dt`:

```
def get_time_series(self):
    self.df['Logon Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Logon Time'], errors='coerce')
    self.df[['Year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'week']] = (pd.Series(df.index)
                                                .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%W')
                                                .str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)).values
    self.df['count'] = df['User Name']
    return self.df.groupby([df['Logon Time'].dt.year, df['Logon Time'].dt.month]).sum().plot.bar()
```

Comment: Hi Ferris, you're right, but I have to start somewhere...anyway, following your answer, I get this error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Removed the .dt in second last line, still got an error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: maybe you should add `self.` before `df`, in your code, you first `from df_count_stats import df, df1`, then when initializing ·class Data_load_compare_0·, if you do not add `self.df`, it will use `df` from the global environment.